# Android 5.0 Lollipop WebView не работает DownloadListener в gmail

Tags: java, android, webview, gmail

Нужно скачать файл при нажатии на ссылку. Код работает на андроид до версии *Lollipop*, начиная с версии *Lollipop* не реагирует на событие нажатия на прикрепленный файл в *gmail*.

```
webView.setDownloadListener(new DownloadListener() { public void onDownloadStart(String url, String userAgent, String contentDisposition, String mimeType, long contentLength) {
        Uri uri = Uri.parse(url);
        Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        i.setDataAndType(uri, mimeType);
        i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
        startActivity(i);
    }
});
```